# Is there a name for this set $\{x\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}\mid x\neq ca^2b^3,\{a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}\mid a+b>2\}\}$?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a name for this set, $\{x \in \mathbb N_{\ge2} \mid x \ne c*a^2b^3, \{a,b,c \in \mathbb N \mid a+b \gt 2\}\}$?

This is the set of integers $\ge 2$ with no duplicate prime factors.

e.g. 12 is 3*2*2 is not a member of the set above. 21 is 3*7 is a member of the set above, as are all prime numbers.

It doesn't seem to be an interesting set as it is not a group under addition. [5+7=12 is a counterexample]

Comment: Do you mean the [square-free integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer)?

Comment: (By the way, the $b$ in your definition is redundant.)

Comment: @TMM Yes, b is redundant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These are the squarefree numbers, [A005117](https://oeis.org/A005117) in the OEIS. Wikipedia has a page [Squarefree integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squarefree_integer), and MathWorld has [Squarefree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squarefree.html).

A possible operation on this set is the 'exclusive product': $m\times n=mn/s$ where $s$ is the largest square dividing $mn.$ This is an abelian group.

Comment: Abelian group isomorphic to ${\bf Z}_2^{\oplus \aleph_0}$. Or rather, it would be, if it included $1$...

Comment: @tomasz: Not quite, since elements like $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdots$ are not in the set. This includes only the strings in $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus\aleph_0}$ with finite Hamming weight. But it's similar, thus my choice of name (exclusive from $\oplus$).

Comment: they're not in the direct sum, either, as opposed to direct product. By ${\bf Z}_2^{\oplus \aleph_0}$ I mean $\bigoplus_{n\in \aleph_0} {\bf Z}_2$.